# How to run MySQL Queries based upon Input box.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Quite new to using PHP and Jquery etc.

Tl;DR :

User modifies a input box using a jQuery Slider. How can i run MySQL statements incorporating that value,on the assumption I'm using PHP.

I'm wanting to make MySQL queries that take the value of a hidden input box and use them to make the queries.
Set up a website with a backend database with a number of news stories broken down into categories.
On the home page the user clicks a link to a specific category which loads that .php page into the main div element using code such as :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sport").on("click", function(){
        $("#div1").load("sport.php",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            if(statusTxt=="error")
                alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
        });

    </script>
```

This page uses a MySQL query to load certain news articles.
These news articles have an assigned value (related to reading ease but that's not important for this question).

The user can use a jquery UI Slider to modify a hidden input box.

I'm wanting the queries that are executed to use this value to return data. But I'm not sure the best way to go about it or where to begin/what to search.

I understand PHP executes once at the beginning , so it could be possible to pass the contents of the input box to PHP and then run it through. However this doesn't seem like the best option and would be impractical.

Is it possible that the script that loads the *category.php* file into the DIV could be passed an argument/variable that contained the value of the query slider? 
If yes , how? That way every time the slider is moved the Div could reload using the current category and the specified parameter for reading ease.

I'm really not sure the best way to go about this or where to begin, but thanks for any and all advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a data-object to `.load()` as the second parameter (making the callback function the third parameter):

```
$('#div1').load('load.php', {slider: $('#slider').val()}, function (...) {...});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: How do you 'receive' this data in the newly loaded page?

Comment: I want to send the Parameter to sport.php, but not exactly sure what i would need to do in sport.php to receive it.

Comment: jQuery makes a normal get request from this, so data passed like this is available in `$_GET` (or `$_POST` if you'd used jquery to make a post request).

Comment: Thanks , ended up using POST as you suggested and all working great now.